# Event Sourcing Resources

Tags: c#, .net, cqrs, event-sourcing

Looking for some suggestions for useful discussion groups, articles, success stories, reference apps, and tooling (.Net) on the subject of event sourcing.

I am already familiar with:

Fowler's article: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html

Greg Young's Article (with downloaded docs in the comments): http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/20/why-use-event-sourcing/

Greg Young's excellent (draft) article on DDDD: [http://abdullin.com/storage/uploads/2010/04/2010-04-16_DDDD_Drafts_by_Greg_Young.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20101025095403if_/http://abdullin.com/storage/uploads/2010/04/2010-04-16_DDDD_Drafts_by_Greg_Young.pdf)

Anything else I should be reading and looking at?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should look at [this implementation of an EventStore](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore) as well as [these](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r) [two](https://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin) implementations of mini-systems based on CQRS with event sourcing.

EDIT (2011-05-18): [NES (.Net Event Sourcing)](https://github.com/elliotritchie/NES) is yet another implementation available to reference.

It may also be worth following the [Google](http://groups.google.com/group/dddcqrs/topics) and [Yahoo](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/domaindrivendesign/) groups related to CQRS & Distributed DDD.

Answer (score 5):

I listen to the [Distributed Podcast](http://distributedpodcast.com/). They give a very good overview of CQRS and partly event sourcing.

Answer (score 1):

I liked this presentation by Erik Rozendaal on lightweight event sourcing:

http://www.slideshare.net/dlrozendaal/exploring-lightweight-event-sourcing-goto-amsterdam-2011

He made a similar presentation at Scala Days 2011; the video is not available yet, but supposedly it will show up here eventually:

http://days2011.scala-lang.org/node/138/301

It seems quite practical!